# div position relative to parent

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position relative a div to his parent to make the yelllow match "GRATUITE" text (like the "MAGIQUE" text, but i used margin and i don't want to use it for the responsive), but it doesn't work the way I want.

```css
.title-accompagne2{
    font-family: 'DM Serif Display',serif;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    color: #f79089 !important;
    font-size: 32px !important;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.surligneur-lettre-gratuite1 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #F8F723;
    width: 150px;
    height: 16px;
    z-index: -5;
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-accompagne2" style="text-align: left; margin-top: 40px !important;">
    <div style="color:#f79089 !important; font-size: 32px !important; margin-left: 0px !important;">
        LA LETTRE
        <span style="z-index: 6;position: relative;">GRATUITE</span>
        <div class="surligneur-lettre-gratuite1"></div>
    </div>
    <p style="color:#f79089 !important; font-size: 32px !important; margin-top: -20px; margin-left: 0px !important;">ET
        <span style="z-index: 6; position: relative;">MAGIQUE</span>
    </p>
    <div
        style="width: 155px; z-index: -5; height: 16px; transform: translate(2.5px, -49px);margin-left: 42px; background-color: #F8F723;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yeah i'm sorry, my english is pretty bad, I'd like to use position relative on the div with the class "surligneur-lettre-gratuite1", to match it's parent (the span) to make the yellow div highlight only the text "GRATUITE", and don't have to use margins like I did on the second one, I hope it's more clear for you now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple task for background, no need to overcomplicate it:

```css
.title-accompagne {
  font-family: 'DM Serif Display', serif;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f79089;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

span {
  background: 
   linear-gradient(#F8F723, #F8F723)  /* coloration */
   bottom  /* position */
   / 
   100% 50% /* width height */
   no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<p class="title-accompagne">
  LA LETTRE <span>GRATUITE</span> <br>ET <span>MAGIQUE</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't know I could do it using background !

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be a pseudo element positioned relative to the span.

```css
.title-accompagne2 {
    font-family: 'DM Serif Display',serif;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    color: #f79089 !important;
    font-size: 32px !important;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.fancy {
  position: relative;
}

.fancy::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #F8F723;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-accompagne2" style="text-align: left; margin-top: 40px !important;">
    <div style="color:#f79089 !important; font-size: 32px !important; margin-left: 0px !important;">
        LA LETTRE
        <span class="fancy" style="z-index: 6;position: relative;">GRATUITE</span>
    </div>
    <p style="color:#f79089 !important; font-size: 32px !important; margin-left: 0px !important;">ET
        <span class="fancy" style="z-index: 6; position: relative;">MAGIQUE</span>
    </p>
</div>
```